# What is the least memory-intensive and efficient way to fill a column with a sequence?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large `data.frame` of size around 6 million rows and 100 variables. I am trying to create a new column and fill the column with row numbers. I have tried the following codes, some of which I retrieved online:

**#1**

```
df$ID  <- 1:nrow(df)
```

**#2**

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble::rowid_to_column(df, "ID")
```

**#3**

```
for (i in 1:6000000) df[i,"ID"] <- i
```

**#4**

```
df[,"ID"] <- c(1:6000000)
```

Most of these gave me the error message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size xxxxx Mb

except for **#4**, which proceeds smoothly and quickly (a few seconds) most of the times.

What are the reasons behind the above differences between methods? Why does **#4** work but not the others? It was like trial-and-error for me as to how I got this done...

---Some info---

My computer is a 64-bit PC with Intel i7 Core and 8GB RAM. I am running 64-bit R 3.4.2 with R Studio v1.1.383. The `object.size` of the data frame is about 3.8 Gb.

Comment: Have you tried `df %>% mutate(ID = row_number())`  Or convert it to `data.table` and do `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, ID := .I]` This should be very efficient

Comment: data table will be very efficient as pointed by akrun

Comment: You guys are right... although I don't really know why these methods differ